# External Tables (HIVE) Choose only a few columns from a file

Tags: hive, external-tables

How can I create a external table setting only a few columns from a file?

Ex: In archive I have  six columns, A,B,C,D,E,F. But in my table i want only A, C, F.

Is It possible?

Comment: Do you intend to modify this data through Hive, or only read it?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of a way to selectively include columns from HDFS files for an external table.  Depending on your use case, it may be sufficient to define a view based on the external table to only include the columns you want.  For example, given the following silly example of an external table:

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table (
    >   A STRING,
    >   B STRING,
    >   C STRING,
    >   D STRING,
    >   E STRING,
    >   F STRING
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE
    > LOCATION '/tmp/ext_table';
OK
Time taken: 0.401 seconds
hive> SELECT * FROM ext_table;
OK
row_1_col_A row_1_col_B     row_1_col_C     row_1_col_D     row_1_col_E     row_1_col_F
row_2_col_A row_2_col_B     row_2_col_C     row_2_col_D     row_2_col_E     row_2_col_F
row_3_col_A row_3_col_B     row_3_col_C     row_3_col_D     row_3_col_E     row_3_col_F
Time taken: 0.222 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Then create a view to only include the columns you want:

```
hive> CREATE VIEW filtered_ext_table AS SELECT A, C, F FROM ext_table;
OK
Time taken: 0.749 seconds
hive> DESCRIBE filtered_ext_table; 
OK
a                           string                              
c                           string                              
f                           string                              
Time taken: 0.266 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM filtered_ext_table;
OK
row_1_col_A row_1_col_C     row_1_col_F
row_2_col_A row_2_col_C     row_2_col_F
row_3_col_A row_3_col_C     row_3_col_F
Time taken: 0.301 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Another way to achieve what you want would require that you have the ability to modify the HDFS files backing your external table - if the columns you are interested in are all near the beginning of each line, then you can define your external table to capture only the first 3 columns (without regard for how many more columns are actually in the file).  For example, with the same data file as above:

```
hive> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ext_table;
OK
Time taken: 1.438 seconds
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table (
    >   A STRING,
    >   B STRING,
    >   C STRING
    > )
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE
    > LOCATION '/tmp/ext_table';
OK
Time taken: 0.734 seconds
hive> SELECT * FROM ext_table;
OK
row_1_col_A row_1_col_B     row_1_col_C
row_2_col_A row_2_col_B     row_2_col_C
row_3_col_A row_3_col_B     row_3_col_C
Time taken: 0.727 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, rchang. This is the way we are using actually. We want to do this in the create statement to simplify our processes. Is it possible?

Comment: @ElderChaves In the general case, I don't know how to do what you want to do.  However, I added another alternative to the end of my answer.  It is a pretty specialized case, namely that the columns you are interested in are near the beginning of each line and you want to just ignore the rest of the line (you are interested in the first 4 out of 12 fields, for example).

Comment: upvoted. the answer was useful. (downvoting without any comment is such a malpractice.)

Answer (score -1):

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849322/oracle-external-table-get-selected-columns-from-the-file)

```
create table tmpdc_ticket(
    SERVICE_ID CHAR(144),
    SERVICE_TYPE CHAR(50),
    CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(200),
    TELEPHONE_NO CHAR(144),
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(144),
    FAULT_STATUS CHAR(50),
    BUSINESS_GROUP CHAR(100)
)
organization external(
    type    oracle_loader
    default directory sample_directory
    access parameters(
        records delimited by newline
        nologfile
        skip 1
        fields terminated by '|'
        missing field values are null
            (DUMMY_1,
             DUMMY_2,
             SERVICE_ID CHAR(144),
             SERVICE_TYPE CHAR(50),
             CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(200),
             TELEPHONE_NO CHAR(144),
             ACCOUNT_NUMBER CHAR(144),
             FAULT_STATUS CHAR(50),
             BUSINESS_GROUP CHAR(100)
        )
    )
    location(sample_directory:'sample_file.txt')
)
reject limit 1
noparallel
nomonitoring;
```

Comment: That is for oracle, not hive.